# IN vs code the double quotes and single quotes are being flags as errors why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Why is it that the double quotes are being picked up as an error and I can't even use contractions words either because they are getting flagged as a issue? This has never been a issue before so why is it starting now?

Comment: Move the mouse pointer over the error and leave a there for a second in order to see the error message. You'll also need to explain what programming language and extension this is all about.

Comment: you somehow have fancy quote marks, probably from cuttting and pasting text. Notice that the early " marks are not flagged. Retype those failing quotes. see https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your language is not recognizing the fancy quotes as allowable string delimiters and so the red underlining under the strings mat be fixed by changing those fancy quotes to normal quotes.

As of vscode v1.63:  Just to know what those orange borders around the quote marks are, the fancy quotes are unexpected unicode characters.  Those orange borders are warnings that there are unexpected or ambiguous unicode characters.

If you add those fancy quote characters to this setting:

`Editor > Unicode Highlight: Allowed Characters`

Just copy and paste your varioucs characters, like `”` into the `Add Item` input.

Or you can **disable** this setting:

`Editor > Unicode Highlight: Non Basic ASCII`

and those warning borders will go away.

Unicode Highlighting of certain features was added to vscode recently.

Comment: My copy of Visual Studio Code doesn't have this setting. Is it provided by a third-party extension?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález v1.63 Stable see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_unicode-highlighting

Comment: Thank you for the update, I hadn't installed yet current major version. Nice feature.